# How plot f(x,y) = x/(1-y) with x^2 + y^2 < 1?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

How do you plot:

f(x,y) = x/(1-y) with x^2 + y^2 < 1

in Mathematica? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: LaTex doesn't work here, though it does on [Mathematica.SE] and [Math.SE].

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the last example in the Mathematica documentation on `RegionPlot > Scope > Presentation`is of use to you.

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
           ColorFunction->Function[{x,y},ColorData["TemperatureMap",x/(1-y)]], 
           ColorFunctionScaling->False, PlotPoints->100]
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of plotting function accept a `RegionFunction` option:

```
DensityPlot[x/(1 - y), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]
]
```

[image]